# Show that the IVP has a unique solution in $\Bbb R$.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, initial-value-problems

Consider the IVP;

$\text{y$^{'}$(t)=f(t)y(t),y(0)=1}$;

where $f$ is continuous.

Show that the IVP has  a  unique solution in $\Bbb R$.

Since $\text{y$^{'}$(t)=f(t)y(t)}\implies \dfrac{y^{'}(t)}{y(t)}=f(t)\implies \ln y=f(t)\implies y(t)=e^{f(t)}+C\implies 1=e^{f(0)}+C\implies C=1-e^{f(0)}$.

Then $y(t)=e^{f(t)}+(1-e^{f(0)})$.

> But I am not sure where to use that $f$ is continuous and how to show that solution is unique?

I am helpless.Please help me.

Comment: I think continuity guarantees the existence of the solution.

Comment: uniqueness generally follows from Picard's Theorem; maybe there is an easier way to see it in this case though

Comment: You forgot to integrate $f$, the argument in the exponential should be an anti-derivative of $f$.

Comment: For every $R>0$ on $[R,R]\times\Bbb R$ you have a global Lipschitz constant $L=\sup_{t\in[R,R]}|f(t)|$.